# Adding a Border to Text on an JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to add an automatic border for text which is used as javascript canvas. I've tried the options like strokeText, strokeStyle and similar, but I can't make that the entered text had border.

This is "AddText" button code:

```
$scope.addText = function() {
    if (canvas.getActiveObject() && canvas.getActiveObject().type == 'text') {
        applyTextStylesSelection();
    }
    else {
        var obj = applyTextStyles(new fabric.Text($scope.text.text));
        obj.setLeft(canvas.getWidth()/2);
        obj.setTop(canvas.getHeight()/2);
        canvas.add(obj);
    }

    $('#meme-text-modal').hide();
};
```

This is the code that formats the text entered in the control (formatting like bolding and font size is selected by the user, but I would like to make text border mandatory

```
    function applyTextStylesSelection() {
    if ($scope.selection && $scope.selection.type == 'text') {
        applyTextStyles($scope.selection);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}

function applyTextStyles(obj) {
    obj.setText($scope.text.text);      
    obj.setFontFamily($scope.text.fontFamily);
    obj.setFontSize($scope.text.fontSize);      
    obj.setFontWeight($scope.text.textStyle.b ? 'bold' : 'normal');
    obj.setTextDecoration($scope.text.textStyle.u ? 'underline' : '');
    obj.setFontStyle($scope.text.textStyle.i ? 'italic' : '');
    obj.setFill($scope.fgColor);

    return obj;
}

function loadSelectedTextOptions() {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    $scope.text.text = obj.getText();
    $scope.text.fontFamily = obj.getFontFamily();
    $scope.text.fontSize = obj.getFontSize();
    $scope.text.textStyle.b = obj.getFontWeight() == 'bold' ? true : false;
    $scope.text.textStyle.u = obj.getTextDecoration() == 'underline' ? true : false;
    $scope.text.textStyle.i = obj.getFontStyle() == 'italic' ? true : false;
    $scope.fgColor = obj.getFill();
    $scope.$digest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these 3 properties of the text object in the function `applyTextStyles` and it will outline the text.

```
obj.setStroke("black");      
obj.setStrokeWidth(5);  
obj.setStrokeLineJoin("round");  // use round to stop corners creating spurs
```